# Race condition in opencl kernel threads

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

If multiple threads are simultaneously writing a single memory location.,there will be a race condition,right??
In my case same is happening..

Consider a module from 'reduce.cl'

```
int i = get_global_id(0);
int n,j;

n = keyMobj[i];                       // this n is the key..It can be either 0 or 1.
for(j=0; j<2; j++)
      sumMobj[n*2+j] += dataMobj[i].dattr[j];        //summing operation.
```

Here, The memory locations
sumMobj===> [...0...,  ....1...] is accessed 4 threads simultaneously &
sumMobj===> [....3...,  ....4...] is accessed 6 threads simultaneously..

Is there any way to still make it parallely,like using locking or semaphore? As this summing is a very big part in my algorithm...

Comment: these are the definitions of sumMobj and dataMobj
typedef struct data
{
  double dattr[10];
  int d_id;
  int bestCent;
}Data;
Data *dataMboj;
and 
double *sumMobj = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * 2 * 2);

Comment: @talonmies It is actually parallel addition problem..in opencl kernel. I just don't know the feasible solution.

Comment: Why don't you use barrier if you suspect there is a race condition ? like barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

Comment: @ocluser  I am having multiple threads which are simultaneously accessing(writing) a single memory location. Would this function 'barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);' be useful in this case? I have not used it before.

Comment: found [this page](http://suhorukov.blogspot.ie/2011/12/opencl-11-atomic-operations-on-floating.html) which explains a method for atomically adding floating point numbers, however you would need to use the cl_khr_int64_base_atomics, and use unions of longs and doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you some hint as I was also facing similar problem.

I can think of three different methods for achieving similar goal:

Consider a simple kernel, assuming you launched 4 (0-3) threads

```
_kernel void addition (int *p)
{
int i = get_local_id(0);
     p[4]+= p[i];
}
```

You want to add values p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], and store the final sum in p[4]. right? i.e:

```
p[4]= p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4]
```

**Method -1**  (no parallelism)

Assign this job to only 1 thread (no parallelism):

```
int i = get_local_id(0);
if (i==0)

{

p[4]+= p[i];

}
```

**Method-2** (with parallelism)

Express your problem as follows:

```
p[4]= p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + 0
```

This is a reduction problem

So launch 3 threads: i=0 to i=2. In first iteration

```
 i=0 finds p[0] + p[1]
 i=1 finds p[2] + p[3]  
 i=2 finds p[4] + 0
```

Now you have three numbers, you apply the same logic as above and add these numbers (with suitable padding of 0 to make it in power of two)

**Method -3** Atomic operations

If you still need to implement this atomically, you can use [atomic_add()](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_add.html):

```
  int fsfunc atomic_add (   volatile __global int *p ,int val)
```

> Description
>
> Read the 32-bit value (referred to as old) stored at location pointed
>   by p. Compute (old + val) and store result at location pointed by p.
>   The function returns old.

This is assuming the data is int type.  Otherwise you can see the [link](http://suhorukov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/opencl-11-atomic-operations-on-floating.html) as suggested above.

Comment: It means if I am using floating point operations,then I don't any other option than using the reduction method, as there isn't any provision of extensions for floating point based atomic operations (as far as my information in concerned). Am I right?

Comment: Apart from reduction you can also see the [link](http://suhorukov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/opencl-11-atomic-operations-on-floating.html) posted by @Slicedpan